# Doing a ~ and ` with less than 3 keystrokes

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

US keyboard users probably don't know, but you need 3 keystrokes on a FR keyboard to do:

- ~ : <kbd>ALT GR</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> then <kbd>SPACE</kbd>
- ` : <kbd>ALT GR</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> then <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> being probably needed because usually, ` is followed by a vowel to be accentuated, ~ is followed by a n (spanish?)

It's very annoying. How to remove this need of space key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution: this allows to produce a

```
`
```

with just one keystroke of <kbd>²</kbd>, using Autohotkey:

```
+²::
Send ²
Return

$²::
Send ``
Send {space}
Return
```

To get `²`, just press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>²</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

These special characters are called dead keys and as you mention they usually are printed only when followed up by a space character. Alternative keyboard layouts (or even usage stiles) are a hassle on windows. You'll have to get your hands a bit dirty, but using either [enter link description here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) or [enter link description here](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) you can modify your keymaps.

If you own a keyboard which offers programmable keys like (usually sold as "gamer keyboards") you could program these to do what you want.

Finally you could consider learning a different/new keyboard layout that is more optimised for programming, which often offer the dead key characters in a non dead key variation. You might start by looking into Dovrak, Neo2 and cousins